# Do all response packages musst pass the load balancer?

Tags: load-balancing

Do all response packages sent from a backend server to a client must pass the load balancer?

Actually I try to solve this Question:

**I have 3 statement. 2 of 3 are true.**

**What is the wrong statement?**

1. Do all response packages sent from a backend server to a client must pass the load balancer?
2. All incoming connections to a cluster service are received by a load balancer.
3. Load balancers can analyze traffic.

Comment: why are people rating my question down?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the load balancing solution that you deploy and how you configure it.

This: http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html
is an example where the response will be sent directly to the client.

This: http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-NAT.html is the same tooling deployed in a pattern where all responses need to pass the loadbalancer.

Comment: why are people rating my question down?